# JetBrains suddenly stopped working on second screen

Tags: windows-7, phpstorm

I've had two screens for a while now (working on windows).
As of this morning, PHPStorm suddenly won't work on the monitor it's been working on for months!

By not working, I mean that when I drag it to its screen (the left screen) the page goes blank and you can't press any buttons. Sometimes the whole window goes black, or it just freezes with 'drag' marks from moving it (changes made while it seems stuck can be seen when moved back to the right screen, so it's just a visual problem).

When I move it back to the right screen it works with no problems.

When I change the direction of the screens under 'screen resolution' the problem disappears (but then the cursor moves between screens in the wrong direction, super uncomfortable!).

My IT guy tried restarting the computer, re-installing drivers, JAVA, nothing seems to work.

Also, he downloaded a different JETBrains product (PYCharm) and it has the same problem.

All other programs seem to work on both windows normally.

Answer (score 1):

Looks similar to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4034664/windows-7-sp1-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-update-kb4034664 (rendering problems on secondary monitors if the screen numbering is not in sequence); please see the article for possible solutions

problem has been resolved with https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4039884/windows-7-update-kb4039884